# How to float menus with getting dynamic height for the menu too?

Tags: html, css, menu

I have been trying with a floated menu to left actually when the menu li got in great number so then the  div just right beneath that get over that menu so what I want is that the below div don't get over it.

Here in picture the footer div got over the menu when I remove `float:left` so it actually get into a straight menu and the footer is not over on the menu then..what I want it to be in the way that it is in float mode too and the div don't get over it please..

Here is image to get some idea:
[image]

And Here is the CSS Code as :

```
ul.quick_categories_menu {
margin: 0;
padding:0;
margin-left: 14px;
margin-top: 40px;
}

ul.quick_categories_menu li {
list-style:none;
float: left;
width:200px;
margin-right: 20px;
text-align: left;
}
```

Here live jsfiddle link please as : http://jsfiddle.net/h1ua00cd/1/

Comment: The below DIV won't *get over it* if you properly clear your floats.

Comment: But I really want that in floating as I want the menu in the image as provided.if you can provide better code without using float to get to that please..it will be great then..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding a ul:after and clear:both

`ul:after {
    content: "";
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    }`

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h1ua00cd/3/

Added the border to demo that it what you put after is not covering the list.